# PDF file is not showing up

Tags: swift

This is my code

```
func createPdfFromView(aView: UIView, saveToDocumentsWithFileName fileName: String)
{
    let pdfData = NSMutableData()
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, aView.bounds, nil)
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage()

    guard let pdfContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }

    aView.layer.renderInContext(pdfContext)
    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext()

    if let documentDirectories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true).first {
        let documentsFileName = documentDirectories + "/" + fileName
        print(documentsFileName)
        let saved = pdfData.writeToFile(documentsFileName, atomically: true)
        print("Saved \(saved)")
    }
}
```

It saved my file successfully. Now i want to view my pdf file. So installed adobe acrobat from app store. Adobe Acrobat app is not showing my pdf file. I want to view my pdf using adobe acrobat

Comment: Share your code with us to help.

Comment: If you're saving the PDF to your app sandbox, It can't be seen by a different application.

Comment: Then where should I have to save

Comment: @Antony You should probably read up about the communication between apps on iOS.